# Bug report: badge tracking data display is wrong

Tags: bug

I've just noticed this, I recently discovered that you could track a tag badge instead of a privilege.

However, the data displayed are wrong on the Activity tab.

See the following data:

[image]

But when I click on the gear icon to see which tag badge I can track, the data for the current badge is totally different that the data posted above:

[image]

Is there a misunderstanding from me ? Because if it is, I feel like there is a usability issue here.

Comment: All I can say is that I wasn't able to reproduce this on my side. The functionality is not specific to the magento website, it is general for the whole stackexchange network. I think you should better post this on meta.stackexchange.com. Just don't forget to mention the website where you were able to reproduce this.

Comment: @QaisarSatti see my own answer, definitely a bug ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so as suggested by Marius I've checked the meta.stackexchange website to see if other people had the same issue.

It's definitely a bug and you can find details about it here: ["Next tag badge" panel score and answers counter discrepancy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy)

Seems like it's not fixed and the only workaround is to:

> Choose a different tag badge to track in the "Select your next badge panel" and then open the panel again to select back the tag badge that you really want to track

Comment: Summoning @pops ...

Comment: I have had the same experience and also found the discussions on SE Meta. They say the bug is too minor for SE to have the focus of the dev team and probably won't be fixed in the near future... :(